# How to best find which TabPage the current control is on?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winforms

I'm making a WinForm with PowerShell and I want to include a button that will remove the current tab, I'm wondering if there's an efficient/fool-proof method to get that?

Currently I'm using this as the event handler:

```
$tabControl = $this.TopLevelControl.Controls | Where-Object {$_.GetType() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.TabControl]}
$tabControl.Controls.Remove($tabControl.SelectedTab)
```

This works fine for what I'm doing, and it's better than something like `$this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Controls.Remove(...`., but it wouldn't work very well if, for example, I had multiple `TabControl` controls (like one on top, one on bottom), or if the `TopLevelControl` isn't a direct parent of the `TabControl`. Does .NET or WinForms already have a method to determine which tab is a parent/ancestor of the control?

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You just need a pseudo-recursive loop. Writing in C#, would be something like: `Control parent = [SomeButton].Parent; while (parent != null && parent.GetType() != typeof(TabControl)) parent = parent.Parent; if (parent != null && parent is TabControl tab) tab.TabPages.Remove(tab.SelectedTab);`